# how to send sms to all contact in save in cell phone in android

Tags: android

I need to build an app with an EditText and a button. When I click on the button the text on the EditText is sent to all the contacts saved into the cell phone. How do I do this?

Comment: THere's SMS sending limits on Android-  apps are capped at the number of messages they can send in a given timeframe.  SO if you want to click a button and send out 100+ texts immediately, it just won't work.

Comment: See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do, show your [mcve]. and tell us what results you get. Show research and errors.